# How to get html5 attributes and values into mvc HiddenFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have following hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" class="deleted" name="Deleted" data-id="@Model.Id" value="@Model.Deleted" />
```

I was wanting to convert this to the MVC helper HiddenFor.

Got this far:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Deleted, new { @class="deleted" })
```

So that covers the class. I also need the data-id attribute and value.

Tried to add the data-id as:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Deleted, new { @class="deleted", data-id="@Model.Id" })
```

Well the helper doesn't seem to like the hyphen in the data-id.

So how to get it in there?

Also how to get the `value="@Model.Deleted"` in there also?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `_` and MVC will convert that to `-` when rendering.

Also you do not need the `@` infront of `Model.Id`. Remove the double quotes also. The below code should work.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Deleted, new { @class="deleted", data_id=Model.Id })
```

And Why are you giving a css class to a hidden field ?

Comment: Works but the Id isn't being evaluated

Comment: what does that means ?  can you explain more ? check whether you are passing the value from controller

Comment: @AnonyMouse: Check my updated answer. That will fix your problem.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Deleted, new { @class="deleted", "data-id"="@Model.Id" })
```